# HTTP OPTIONS error in Phil Sturgeon's Codeigniter Restserver and Backbone.js

Tags: codeigniter, rest, backbone.js, http-options-method, codeigniter-restserver

My `backbone.js` application throwing an HTTP OPTIONS not found error when I try to save a model to my restful web service that's located on another host/URL.

Based on my research, I gathered from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727696/backbonejs-cors-and-save-method) that :

> a request would constantly send an OPTIONS http request header, and not trigger the POST request at all.
>
> Apparently CORS with requests that will "cause side-effects on user data" will make your browser "preflight" the request with the OPTIONS request header to check for approval, before actually sending your intended HTTP request method.

I tried to get around this by:

- Settting emulateHTTP in Backbone to true.

> Backbone.emulateHTTP = true;

- I also allowed allowed all CORS and CSRF options in the header.

  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");

The application crashed when the `Backbone.emulateHTTP` line of code was introduced.

Is there a way to respond to OPTIONS request in CodeIgniter RESTServer and are there any other alternatives to allow either disable this request from talking place?

---

I found [this on Github](https://github.com/clockworkgeek/codeigniter-restserver-extra-verbs) as one solution. I am not sure if I should use it as it seems a bit outdated.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I encountered exactly the same problem.  To solve it I have a MY_REST_Controller.php in core and all my REST API controllers use it as a base class.  I simply added a constructor like this to handle OPTIONS requests.

```
function __construct() {

    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
    $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    if($method == "OPTIONS") {
        die();
    }
    parent::__construct();
}
```

This just checks if the request type is OPTIONS and if so just dies out which return a code 200 for the request.

Comment: After searching for hours; this was the solution. Thanks :)

Comment: On top of it we can add  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  like this, header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']); 

So that here you can check allow which domain access to your api's.

Comment: probably better to send a 204 response:  so code would be:  parent::__construct();
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "OPTIONS") {
   $this->response(NULL,HTTP_NO_CONTENT);
   return;
  }

Comment: May I know why do you need to deny all 'OPTIONS' request method?

Comment: It works in local else we need to live and upload to server. Am using codeigniter and react js in front end. Where we have to put this.?

Answer (score 7):

You can also modify the `$allowed_http_methods` property in your subclass to exclude the options method. Previous versions of REST_controller did nothing with **OPTIONS** and adding this line seems to mimic that behavior:

```
protected $allowed_http_methods = array('get', 'delete', 'post', 'put');
```

Comment: solves [POST request with AngularJS fails with preflight OPTION status code = 404 with CodeIgniter ResetServer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23954433/802365)

Comment: This is much cleaner that the higher ranking answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this way:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, x_requested_with");

if ( "OPTIONS" === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) {
    die();
}
```

Pay attention to add x_requested_with in Access-Control-Allow-Headers.