# Cross-Domain pre-flight OPTIONS forbidden

Tags: php, jquery, apache, codeigniter, cors

### **Updated code and the cause further down**

---

I'm building a client side application that has the capabilities to talk to [Phil Sturgeons code igniter rest application](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver).

The issue is when trying to request the login method I am prompted by `OPTIONS http://site/api/login 403 (Forbidden)` and `OPTIONS http://site/api/login Invalid HTTP status code 403`.

I've enabled CORS both on server and apache level in hopes it might change the response messages. In `application/config/config.php`

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, X-AUTH-TOKEN');
// header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, true, 200'); <- tried this also
```

On Apache level in **httpd.conf**

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"                   
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE"
```

The jQuery code, I've commented out previous approaches on sending different headers. If `X-API-KEY` isn't specified it will return the appropriate error **`{"status":false,"error":"Invalid API Key."}`**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://site/api/login",
    data: {data : encrypted_login},
    headers: {"X-API-KEY": "_API_KEY_"},
    // headers: {"X-API-KEY": "_API_KEY_", "Content-Type":  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
    // beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
        // xhr.overrideMimeType( "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;" );
        // xhr.setRequestHeader('X-API-KEY', '_API_KEY_');
        // xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;');
        // Tried different Content-Types to try avoid the pre-flight call
    // },
    // crossDomain: true,
    // dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
       console.log('success' + data); // show response from the php script.
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(errorThrown); // throws empty
    },
    fail: function(data) {
        console.log('fail login : ',data);
    }
});
```

With the newest update of the rest library support for OPTION, PATCH and HEAD has been added. I wrote a method that would accomodate the login options call that always returns 200. Which unfortunately didn't change the situation.

```
function login_options(){
    $this->response(array('response' => 'Hello World!'), 200);
}
```

Note: When using POSTMAN chrome extension all calls including that to login_options works perfectly.

Edit: Has something to do with Phil Sturgeons library denying it, the root of the site accepts pre-flight requests. Using `3.0.0-pre` build version

Edit: Has to do with passing headers to the request. Without this and API keys disabled it works.

---

---

---

### **Update:**

The problem is due to using virtual host names. Why this is happening I'm unsure, I've tested with 3 blank instalments of [Phil Sturgeons rest server](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver) on 2 different machines and was able to replicate the problem on all of them.

It didn't matter how I had setup the virtual host, I tried these two approaches.

**My httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot "/Users/admin/Sites/rest_library"
ServerName rest_library
ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/rest_library-error_log"
CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/rest_library-access_log" common
<Directory "/Users/admin/Sites">
    AllowOverride All
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Works mates httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName restserver
  DocumentRoot "/Users/admin/Sites/codeigniter-restserver"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "/Users/admin/Sites/codeigniter-restserver">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

To get around this I have to reference everything as `http://localhost/rest_library/api/` instead. This also happens on servers with CNAMES, haven't tested top level site yet. Using the exact same code I was able to get the non virtual host one working while the one with a virtual host was failing.

Also because you can't set `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` as a wildcard while `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` is set I used a less reliable method to get around

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change - to _ in header names.

https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver/blob/4fb294b45607d394871a9d1cb9828e789195826a/application/libraries/REST_Controller.php#L681

Comment: Unfortunately it's still the same. I renamed it to `X_API_KEY` and get stopped on the preflight OPTIONS request. Thanks for the suggestion, wasn't something I had actually tried yet!

Comment: So you are no longer getting "Invalid API Key." ?

Comment: Nope getting `403 Invalid HTTP Status`. We've worked out the issue but trying to find a solution to fixing it before adding it as an answer. [Also as of Apache 2.4 underscores in headers are silently dropped.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/new_features_2_4.html)

Comment: Try to send empty response body in `function login_options(){`. Also try different browser.

Comment: Doesn't even reach the construct. I've tried on safari, firefox and chrome

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer in another Stack Overflow thread and it works!

You need to detect method and if it's OPTIONS then exit php by die()!

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19310265/3679394