# POST request with AngularJS fails with preflight OPTION status code = 404 with CodeIgniter ResetServer

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter, http-post, cors, codeigniter-restserver

My front-end application is running on a `grunt` live server on port `9100`, while my PHP server is on the port `80`. The host is the same, just the port differ.

When I send a `POST` request to `http://dev.site.dev/api/gist` with some `JSON` data, I got an error `404` on the preflight `OPTIONS` request.

I already added the `CORS` headers in apache configuration:

```apache
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, accept, content-type"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

```
and restart the server but still got the issue.

Should I add an `index_option()` method in my `gist` controller ? Or the problem is somewhere else ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I described in my [answer on the `CodeIgniter` bug tracker for this "issue" #313](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver/issues/313), there is several solutions.

### Application wide

I found a solution from [HTTP OPTIONS error in Phil Sturgeon's Codeigniter Restserver and Backbone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20511188/802365), which is to remove `otpions` from the list of value in `$allowed_http_methods`:

```php
// protected $allowed_http_methods = array('get', 'delete', 'post', 'put', 'options', 'patch', 'head');
   protected $allowed_http_methods = array('get', 'delete', 'post', 'put', 'patch', 'head');
```

### Resource's focused

Another solution is to simply **implement the `index_options()`**.

It didn't work for me the first time due to a **typo** (it's **`OPTIONS` is plural** ). And with this solution no more need to temper with `applications/libraries/REST_Controller.php`:

```php
public function index_options() {
    return $this->response(NULL, 200);
}
```

Now the preflight `OPTION` request is always true so the `POST` request is sent and everything works :)

Comment: That was an outstanding answer Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have to add the `index_options()` method.

I had the same problem and it only worked when i added the OPTIONS method with the same arguments as my POST method.

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was a routing problem.

What I did is overide the 404 routing. After that, the request got through the routing and the rest server did all the rest.

This is what I put in my routes.php:

```
$route['404_override'] = 'auth/options';
```