# URL access in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have create a project in codeigniter.I had set a `base_url` in config.php as http://testproject.com/test/

Now I can able access the application with that url (http://testproject.com/test/) and also I have able to login,but I cannot able to access the application with the URL  www.testproject.com/test/ just here I have add a www before domain name.

I am getting the error as "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http".

In config.php I have set as a base url http://www.testproject.com/test/ now I have able to access the application with the url www.testproject.com/test/

But cannot able to access with the url "http://testproject.com/test/" getting the error as "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http".

```
I have set as uri_protocol 'AUTO';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

My .htaccess file looks like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Any one help me on this issue

Comment: Can you try setting it to `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';`

Comment: Yes, I am getting the same error

Comment: Without codeigniter setup,is your site getting accessed with both "www" and "non-www" ?

Comment: Without set I cannot able to access domain name. It getting IP address like
http://172.14.1.202/testproject.com/test.
Now I am not able to access css,js files

Comment: See test project.com is pointed to your IP.so you should be able to access it by domain name or IP address.

Comment: It's a CORS issue. You need to look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25702991/enabling-cors-in-codeigniter-restserver-by-chriskacerguis