# I am getting post response in network tab but still shows error in console

Tags: angular, codeigniter, http, response

I am writing a post method in angular to post some data I am returning JSON in Codeigniter.

this is service:

```
public userlogin(data) {
  let uploadURL = `myurl`;

  const requestOptions: Object = {
    responseType: 'json'
  }    
   return this.http.post<any>(uploadURL, data,requestOptions).pipe(map((responce) => {
    console.log(responce);
    return responce;
  })
  );
}
```

In my component:

```
this.services.postuser(formData).subscribe(
  (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  }
);
```

following error, I am getting in the console
[image: Http error response to my post method]

and here is a screenshot to my network tab where the response is JSON 
[image]

I have gone through a lot of stack overflow questions and answers but the solution is not working for me.
I also changed post method response from JSON to text and response type in post method to text still receiving the same error.

backend function for post:

```
public function user_login()
    {
    if(is_array($_POST) && sizeof($_POST) >0){

       $where_array = array(
        'username'=>$this->input->post('username'),
        'password'=>$this->input->post('password')
        );

            $result = $this->Admin_model->checkuser($where_array);
            // print_r($result); die;
            if($result == "user not found" || $result == "incorrect password")
            {
                $json_data = array("Code"=>"1","data"=>$result);
                echo json_encode($json_data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

            }else{
                 $json_data = array("Code"=>"0","data" => "Login successfull");
                 echo json_encode($json_data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
            }
     }   
 }
```

Comment: Error responses can also contain a response body. This is what's happening here.

Comment: can you please elaborate. I am pretty much confused by a lot of answers what exactly should i do

Comment: The [official doc](https://angular.io/guide/http) has it all. Scroll down to error handling.

Comment: as per official docs i did error handling i got error ---->
Backend returned code 0, body was: [object ProgressEvent]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solved by myself:

I found the issue was not about the request I was sending or the response.
actually, it was a cors error because the server does not set to accept the cross-origin request.

first, I install [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/?src=search) Firefox extension to test the problem then i got the response.

so After testing,In my ci file I set the origin to '*' to allow all origin.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Answer (score 0):

In my personal experience working with asp.net core backend (sql database) and NodeJS express backend (mongoDB)

inside Angular Front-end :

inside my services that return Observable
simply return post request , like this :

```
return this.http.post(url, data, options);
```

in the component that use the service going to be like this :

```
this.service.postMethod(data).subscribe((res)=>{}, (err)=>{});
```

Comment: if you response with json , do this : JSON.stringify(res)

Comment: check error that income from backend, first get error properties by using this
Object.getOwnPropertyNames();
and make sure you send data object in same way your back end read it , property names have to match

Comment: and options, do not send unnecessary options to your back end

Comment: yes i did that and now i am getting Backend returned code 0, body was: [object ProgressEvent]

Comment: so if error happening when ProgressEvent is going on , i think something is not right when HttpClient post data to backend
can you give me response code inside your back end ?

Comment: yeah sure!!
reposnse :-
$json_data = array("data"=>$result);
echo json_encode($json_data);

Comment: how your backend work with request ?
please give me that part of backend code going to work with login request.
I want to see how your back end see username and password

Comment: personally , before send data to backend , turn them into js object like this :
data = {
 username: 'usename',
password: 'password'
}

Comment: i am sending formdata

Comment: It's look like your back end cannot see the username value.
if formData is a form group type, add .value at the end of formData, like this:
this.services.postuser(formData.value).subscribe(
  (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  }
);

Comment: but i am getting response as shown in screenshot of network tab

Comment: yes , and response says that
Code 1 , User not found

Comment: that is my response set in my ci model if user not found

Comment: ok , and if i understand your question , you have the your username and password inside your database , and your back-end can not retrieve that , am i right ?

Comment: no my api's are working fine and tested on postman and while using in angular form data is getting retrieved in ci and response is also sent properly.

Comment: also this is warning:

zone-evergreen.js:2952 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response "url" with MIME type application/json. See "url" for more details.

but if cors are added it doesnt sent response at all

Comment: thanks to you to you clarify my error handling issues too.

Answer (score 0):

Also set content type json so it would not throw any other error just to be sure.

put below code on top of the php file:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

For refer this [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25703960/12030620)