# XmlHttpRequest with custom headers: Response for preflight doesn't pass access control check

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a problem with an ajax GET Request on REST Server. I made some tests and i will post them here.

In the REST Server i've two methods:

- 1) resource_new_get (returns json data and needs no custom header)
- 2)
  resource_api_new_get (resurns same json data as the first, but needs an Api-Key custom header)

This is the javascript code that performs the ajax request on the server (on the resource_new_get method):

```
app.updateResources = function(data)
  {
    if(data == null)
    {
      $.ajax(
      {
        url: 'http://<remotehost>/api/events/resource_new?id_event=<ID>',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(d)
        {
          console.log(d);
        },
        error: function(error)
        {
          console.log('error ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        }
      });
    }
    else
    {
      ...
    }
  };
```

In this case, ajax request runs fine and i'm able to obtain the json response from the server.

But when i perform a request to resource_api_new adding custom headers as follows:

```
app.updateResources = function(data)
{
if(data == null)
{
     $.ajax(
     {
           url: 'http://<remotehost>/api/events/resource_api_new?id_event=<ID>',
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {'Api-Key': '<my_token>'},
            success: function(d)
            {
              console.log(d);
            },
            error: function(error)
            {
              console.log('error ' + JSON.stringify(error));
            }
          });
        }
        else
        {
          ...
        }
      };
```

Which needs a token identified by 'Api-Key' key in the headers to return the json response, error function fires and returns this:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://<remotehost>/v2/index.php/api/events/resource_api_new?id_event=<ID>. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://<myhost>' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

When i add at the top of the php file, that contains REST Server, the following line:

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

The response return "simply" HTTP status code 404, as follows:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.gtmasterclub.it/v2/index.php/api/eventi/relatori_api_new?id_evento=159. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution at the problem:

The Api-Key Header was not included in Access-Control-Allow-Headers and i added simply this:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Api-Key
```

Also, i added a constructor to handle the OPTIONS request, as explained here:

[HTTP OPTIONS error in Phil Sturgeon's Codeigniter Restserver and Backbone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602099/http-options-error-in-phil-sturgeons-codeigniter-restserver-and-backbone-js)

```
function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
        if($method == "OPTIONS") {
            log_message('debug', 'method OPTIONS called');
            die();
        }
}
```

And, in the client script i deleted:

```
data-type: 'json',
```