# Angular 4 Http request with codeigniter API error with CORS, cannot access API function

Tags: php, angular, api, codeigniter

I have api on localhost (xampp) / codeigniter and im trying to access it via angular 4 and the browser keeps showing this error in the console. api works fine in postman.

[Firefox]:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://lvh.me/ci-abc/api/get_alltasks. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

[Chrome]:

> Failed to load http://lvh.me/ci-abc/api/get_alltasks: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I have tried changing API url to localhost and 127.0.0.1 as well but didn't work. I am a beginner developer so pardon me if im missing something.

Service function in Angular 4

```
gettasks()
  {
    return this.http.get('http://lvh.me/ci-abc/api/get_alltasks')
    .map(res=>res.json());
  }
```

API function in codeigniter

```
function get_alltasks_get()
    {
        {
            $result = $this->todo_model->get_alltasks();

            if ($result) {
                $this->response($result, 200);
            } else {
                $this->response("No record found", 404);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CORS on PHP**

> Browsers send specific [HTTP headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) for cross-site requests
>   initiated from within [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). It
>   also expects to see specific HTTP headers sent back with cross-site
>   responses.
>
> An overview of these headers, including sample JavaScript code that
>   initiates requests and processes responses from the server, as well as
>   a discussion of each header, [can be found in the HTTP Access Control
>   (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) article and should be read as a companion article to this
>   one.
>
> and should be read as a companion article to this one. [This
>   article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Server-Side_Access_Control) covers processing **Access Control Requests** and
>   formulating **Access Control Responses** in PHP.

If you don't have access to configure Apache, you can still send the header from a PHP script. It's a case of adding the following to your PHP scripts:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Comment: `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`

I put this in the constructor of my API controller and it worked! thanks

Comment: and when you add headding to your php script put it in the top
@YousufKhan Mark it as an answer and give it an upvote then

Answer (score 1):

It's not Angular problem, the problem caused because you're not in the same domain as your server is, for example, if you try to send a request to `example.com` from `johndoe.com` you will get the error and it's browser that blocks the request!

The browser first makes a `header` request and if the request is allowed, the next request with the real method type will be issued.

For CodeIgniter, try adding OPTIONS to the allowed methods.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding");
```

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602099/http-options-error-in-phil-sturgeons-codeigniter-restserver-and-backbone-js?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I've just spend sometime on this and i found out a couple things:

- start with studying your request you do from angular to the backend. In the request headers there is a key called 'origin: ...' this is the origin that is asked for.
- Codeigniter uses a concept called 'filters' which can be compared to laravel's middleware or angulars interceptors. They do something with the request. In this case add a header.
- You need to register those filters in Config/Filters.php for the application to use them.

So here is what i did:

- Create a new CorsFilter.php under App\Filters

```
use CodeIgniter\config\Services;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\Response;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\FilterInterface;


class CorsFilter implements FilterInterface
{
    public function after(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, $arguments = null)
    {


    }

    public function before(RequestInterface $request, $arguments = null)
    {
        if (array_key_exists('HTTP_ORIGIN', $_SERVER)) {
            $origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];
        } else if (array_key_exists('HTTP_REFERER', $_SERVER)) {
            $origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
        } else {
            $origin = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }
        $allowed_domains = array(
            'http://localhost:4200',
            // your origin from request headers goes here
        );


        if (in_array($origin, $allowed_domains)) {
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $origin);
        }
        //these headers are always needed for an api call
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-API-KEY, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, observe, enctype, Content-Length, X-Csrf-Token");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
        header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
        header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
        $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
        //this handles the required 'ok' for the preflight check
        if ($method == "OPTIONS") {
            header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK CORS");
            die();
        }

    }


}
```

register the filter in App\config\Filters.php

```
namespace Config;

use CodeIgniter\Config\BaseConfig;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\CSRF;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\DebugToolbar;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\Honeypot;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\InvalidChars;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\SecureHeaders;
use App\Filters\CorsFilter;

class Filters extends BaseConfig
{
    /**
     * Configures aliases for Filter classes to
     * make reading things nicer and simpler.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $aliases = [
        'csrf'          => CSRF::class,
        'toolbar'       => DebugToolbar::class,
        'honeypot'      => Honeypot::class,
        'invalidchars'  => InvalidChars::class,
        'secureheaders' => SecureHeaders::class,
        'cors'          => CorsFilter::class
    ];

    /**
     * List of filter aliases that are always
     * applied before and after every request.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $globals = [
        'before' => [
            'cors'
            // 'honeypot',
            // 'csrf',
            // 'invalidchars',
        ],
        'after' => [
            'toolbar',
            // 'honeypot',
            // 'secureheaders',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * List of filter aliases that works on a
     * particular HTTP method (GET, POST, etc.).
     *
     * Example:
     * 'post' => ['foo', 'bar']
     *
     * If you use this, you should disable auto-routing because auto-routing
     * permits any HTTP method to access a controller. Accessing the controller
     * with a method you don’t expect could bypass the filter.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $methods = [];

    /**
     * List of filter aliases that should run on any
     * before or after URI patterns.
     *
     * Example:
     * 'isLoggedIn' => ['before' => ['account/*', 'profiles/*']]
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $filters = [];
}
```

Now every request from the frontend is allowed into the backend. Hope this makes sense and helps anyone struggling with this.